# How to iterate over columns in a df and compare value with previous column and perform a action in Python

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, dataframe, delete-row

The operation I am trying to perform is similar to this mysql delete statement :

```
   DELETE FROM ABCD WHERE val_2001>val_2000*1.5 OR val_2001>val_1999*POW(1.5,2);
```

And the column_names varies from val_2001 to val_2017.

All the data from the table ABCD is dumped into a csv and loaded into df.

How to iterate over each column and compare with previous column and perform a delete? ( new to python)

The table data sample :

```
val_2000   val_2001        val_2002            val_2003
100     112.058663384525    119.070787312921    117.033250060214
100     118.300395256917    124.655238202362    128.723125524235
100     109.333236619151    116.785836024946    117.390803371386
100     120.954175930764    126.099776250454    124.491022271481
100     107.776153227575    105.560100052722    108.07490649383
100     151.596517146962    306.608812920781    124.610273175528
```

Note: there are columns which need not be iterated as well.

The sample output :

```
val_2000   val_2001        val_2002            val_2003
100     112.058663384525    119.070787312921    117.033250060214
100     118.300395256917    124.655238202362    128.723125524235
100     109.333236619151    116.785836024946    117.390803371386
100     120.954175930764    126.099776250454    124.491022271481
100     107.776153227575    105.560100052722    108.07490649383
100     NULL                   NULL             124.610273175528
```

EDIT : - Currently trying this way:

```
    df = pd.read_csv("singleDataFile.csv")
   for values in xrange(2000,2016):
        val2 = values+1
        df['val_'+str(val2)] = df['val_'+str(val2)].where((df['val_'+str(val2)]>df['val_'+str(values)]*1.5) |  (df['val_'+str(val2)]<df['val_'+str(values)]*0.75))

   print(df)
```

Getting a format error

Comment: Are you comparing any value in one column to any value in the other and if greater, dump the entire column?

Comment: Can you show the DataFrame you would like to get as output?

Comment: @pshep123, Cell to cell comparision and deleting only the present cell.

Comment: @splinter added the output table (expected)

Comment: @Viv notice that it is not clear from your post why you want a null in the last column of val_2002

Comment: thats when it is comparing between val_2001 and val 2002 ( second iteration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the [Series.where](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html) function on the columns you want to change. For example the first column can be acheived by:

```
df['val_2001'] = df['val_2001'].where( df['val_2001']>df['val_2000']*1.5 )
```

**Edit** (in response to OP comment): You can add OR using the python notation `|`, for example, as follows:

```
df['val_2001'] = df['val_2001'].where( (df['val_2001']>df['val_2000']*1.5) |  (df['val_2001']<df['val_2000']*0.75) )
```

Comment: getting an error with TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Comment: I can take a look. Please post all of the code above

Comment: `code` df = pd.read_csv("singleDataFile.csv")
for values in xrange(2000,2016):
    val2 = values+1
    df['val_'+str(val2)] = df['val_'+str(val2)].where( (df['val_'+str(val2)]>df['val_'+str(values)]*1.5) |  (df['val_'+str(val2)]<df['val_'+str(values)]*0.75))
`code`
print(df)

Answer (score 2):

This code creates a random DataFrame that fairly closely mimics your DataFrame.  It seems one of the key components of your questions was iterating through multiple columns, which this does (via pandas).

Build DataFrame:

```
cols = [ 'val_{}'.format(c) for c in range(2000, 2018)]

d = {}
for c in cols:
    d[c] = np.random.rand(10) * 200 + 100

df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns = cols)
```

Output:

```
     val_2000    val_2001    val_2002    val_2003    val_2004    val_2005  \
0  138.795742  178.467087  131.461771  151.475698  217.449107  107.680520   
1  127.857106  217.484552  248.528498  155.661208  281.914679  211.313490   
2  278.366253  137.543827  167.605495  129.869768  272.923010  190.659691   
3  221.798435  206.622385  145.636888  236.499951  212.404028  122.954408   
4  122.994183  299.793792  171.987895  246.948802  290.938506  127.846811   
5  264.400326  203.226235  121.972832  137.858361  161.812761  270.464277   
6  156.253907  280.101596  138.100352  164.018757  121.044386  297.869079   
7  186.572007  146.406624  110.309996  270.895300  101.975819  229.314098   
8  195.470896  286.125937  251.778581  259.112738  207.539354  127.895095   
9  168.135585  261.295740  203.234246  279.825177  188.648541  197.145975
```

Core Code:

```
df[(df.shift(axis = 1) > df * 1.5) | (df.shift(axis = 1) < df * 0.75)] = 'NULL'
```

Output:

```
     val_2000 val_2001    val_2002 val_2003 val_2004 val_2005   \
0  138.795742  178.467  131.461771  151.476     NULL  107.681 
1  127.857106     NULL  248.528498  155.661     NULL  211.313  
2  278.366253  137.544  167.605495   129.87     NULL   190.66  
3  221.798435  206.622  145.636888     NULL  212.404  122.954     
4  122.994183     NULL  171.987895     NULL  290.939  127.847  
5  264.400326  203.226  121.972832  137.858  161.813     NULL  
6  156.253907     NULL  138.100352  164.019  121.044     NULL  
7  186.572007  146.407  110.309996     NULL  101.976     NULL   
8  195.470896     NULL  251.778581  259.113  207.539  127.895     
9  168.135585     NULL  203.234246     NULL  188.649  197.146
```

Comment: getting an error with TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Comment: Just change any `int` Series to `float`. It's probably your first column: `df['val_2000'].astype(float)`

Comment: Hi Viv - that's a separate question, one which I'm sure has been answered in many a SO post.

Comment: Sorry I meant, I have started with cols = [ 'val_{}'.format(c) for c in range(2000, 2018)], so it is starting from val_2000 while iteration.. \n

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame(df_a, columns = cols) ( so cols will start from val_2000 right?